# Checking proper internet is available or not

Tags: android, android-networking

I am facing a situation regrading the internet in my Android app. I am checking the internet availability in my app. But I want a proper checking the connectivity as well. Right now if my internet is connected but signal is not getting.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ){
    //do what ever
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please activate the internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

if signal was lost it not showing `internet is not available`. So I want some code for how to check the signal in each and every time.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
  public final boolean isInternetON(Context context) {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netinfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netinfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isAvailable())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isAvailable())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;

    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;

}
```

Comment: His situation is different Murali. Say for example sometimes u may have connected to wifi but wifi router's dsl (or network cable) is disconnected.

Comment: @MayuMayooresan it will return false value. based on this boolean value easily identify net was not connected